# Android: Text size set to all resolution

Tags: android, textview, standards

I set font size to 15dp for TextView

This font standard for mobile resolution but for tablet not standard

Mobile version : i.stack.imgur.com/zqNmw.png

Tablet version : i.stack.imgur.com/KQFOV.png

I want tablet version this : i.stack.imgur.com/KHaPP.png

I want font size ratio of resolution

Comment: `I set font size to 15dp` which is **wrong** Font sizes must be given in **sp**, not in dp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably learn more about android size units and their differences.

- `dp` is density independent pixel. This is used instead of normal pixels is because android devices have various screen densities, or dot pitch. e.g. For a 50px by 50px square, it would appear smaller when the screen density is high. So how to prevent this? Use dp! It makes sure that whatever screen density, the thing always appear in the same actual size.
- `sp` is scale dependent pixels. This is usually preferred when you are dealing with text. When the screen is larger, you want the text to be larger, right? Use sp then! It ensures that the text size grows when the screen size is larger.

For tl;dr, **JUST USE SP FOR TEXT!**

Comment: Oh ! i use sp for textview and imageview but not work !

Comment: @Mohammad Can you show me your code?

Comment: Please see this image : http://i63.tinypic.com/2e34v0w.jpg

Comment: I don't think you should use sp for width & height. @Mohammad

Comment: I want use for width and height , i can ?

Answer (score 0):

```
int heightPixels, width, height;

float scaleFactor, heightDp, DiffheightDp;

WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    width = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    height = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    heightPixels = metrics.heightPixels;
    scaleFactor = metrics.density;
    heightDp = heightPixels / scaleFactor;

if(height > width ){
    DiffheightDp = 592.0;
}else{
    DiffheightDp  = 360.0
}

textView.setTextSize((float) ((15.0 / DiffheightDp) * heightDp));

//15.0 is size you want.
```

Comment: You should explain your code more. Code-only answers are not encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Using the sp unit is recommended for text because in ICS and above (could be Honeycomb too, correct me if I'm wrong), there is a preference for a user's font size. So, if you're using Gingerbread or lower, you won't be able to find this setting.

The preference is under Settings, Display, Font Size. There's also an option under Settings, Accessibility, Large text, too.

In a nut shell: always give text sizes in sp not in dp